# OpenFire, HTTP-BIND and performance

Tags: performance, chat, xmpp, openfire

I'm looking into getting an openfire server started and setting up a strophe.js client to connect to it. My concern is that using http-bind might be costly in terms of performance versus making a straight on XMPP connection.

Can anyone tell me whether my concern is relevant or not? And if so, to what extend?

The alternative would be to use a flash proxy for all communication with OpenFire.

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking about the performance of BOSH in Openfire, or BOSH in general?

Comment: In general, though if you have info to share on Openfire's implementation I would be happy to hear it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BOSH is more verbose than normal XMPP, especially when idle.  An idle BOSH connection might be about 2 HTTP requests per minute, while a normal connection can sit idle for hours or even days without sending a single packet (in theory, in practice you'll have pings and keepalives to combat NATs and broken firewalls).

But, the only real way to know is to **benchmark**.  Depending on your use case, and what your clients are (will be) doing, the difference might be negligible, or not.

Answer (score 1):

Basics:

```
Socket - zero overhead.

HTTP - requests even on IDLE session.
```

I doubt that you will have 1M users at once, but if you are aiming for it, then conection-less protocol like http will be much better, as I'm not sure that any OS can support that kind of connected socket volume.

Also, you can tie your OpenFires together, form a farm, and you'll have nice scalability there.

Answer (score 1):

we used Openfire and BOSH with about 400 concurrent users in the same MUC Channel. 
What we noticed is that Openfire leaks memory. We had about 1.5-2 GB of memory used and got constant out of memory exceptions. 
Also the BOSH Implementation of Openfire is pretty bad. We switched then to [punjab](https://github.com/twonds/punjab) which was better but couldn't solve the openfire issue.

We're now using ejabberd with their built-in http-bind implementation and it scales pretty well. Load on the server having the ejabberd running is nearly 0.

At the moment we face the problem that our 5 webservers which we use to handle the chat load are sometimes overloaded at about 200 connected Users.
I'm trying to use websockets now but it seems that it doesn't work yet. 
Maybe redirecting the http-bind not via Apache rewrite rule but directly on a loadbalancer/proxy would solve the issue but I couldn't find a way on how to do this atm.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, may I ask how long ago you used Openfire? They're updates have suffered a LONG hiatus but they seem to be maintaining it again as of last year. For your proxy issue, I personally used the apache proxy mod for this, with the following config: http://pastebin.com/zEJ1ZZNq. Of course I have not been able to do any serious load testing as of yet.

Comment: We used it last year, ca. from August to September/October. We used afaik 3.7.0 before we switched to ejabberd. What you need to consider is that MUC (as we used it in our setup) needs more ressources than "standard" jabber services. Maybe it'll work for your case. Regarding the proxy: Interesting setup, I'll need to test that (if it's better like this). We had (and still have) our setup like [this](https://github.com/candy-chat/candy/wiki/HTTP-Proxy-Configuration).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using node.js and http://code.google.com/p/node-xmpp-bosh as I faced some difficulties to connect directly to Openfire via BOSH.

I have a production site running with node.js configured to proxy all BOSH requests and it works like a charm (around 50 concurrent users). The only downside so far: in the Openfire admin console you will not see the actual IP address of the connected clients, only the local server address will show up as Openfire get's the connection from the node.js server.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to comment on my question, but you're not really attempting to answer it. My question is about performance, and how big of an impact one solution can have on it versus another. For the record I'm looking at an implementation for potentially thousands, if not millions, of users.